# CWM recovery can't find the kernel image

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting, rom-flashing, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-sl

I wanted to root and upgrade my Galaxy i9003 to Jelly Bean. I followed [this guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1894737) and flashed CWM on the phone. But then the phone doesn't boot in normal mode and Samsumg logo keeps flashing forever.

I've put the CM 11 kernel on the external card but when I boot into recovery, CWM can't find it. The list of directories (on the sd card) it shows is not complete and it shows the same directories on the internal card even after I did a factory reset and wiped the caches.

Any way to save the day? Can I flash the CM 11 kernel using Odin?

Comment: Did you follow the directions in the order prescribed? Did you use the corrrect version of CWM? Did you select the right files? Did you clear cache and dalvik-cache? Did you select the proper kernel? …It might be a pain, but restart from scratch (also a freshly formatted SD card). It could be a step wasn't followed properly. As to using Odin, you need to figure out where the problem is first.

Comment: I did all of that. I'm not sure I'm using the right CWM kernel. In the guide that I linked there are 2 links to the kernel download. One of them seems to be generic and the other one has different downloads for various firmware. I used the generic one. I couldn't find the kernel for my firmware. maybe that's the problem. But I can't remember the firmware name! I just flashed the generic kernel again and the phone is stuck in reboot.

Comment: Those 2 files you are talking about are for firmware, not the kernel. You need to search for that. Figure out which firmware that you have then pick from [Kernel search page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/sitesearch.php?q=i9003%20kernel). Then continue with the guide

Comment: I can't remember the babseband version and the phone doesn't boot so I can't find it out. I remember I couldn't find a kernel specific for it back then. Is there any way to erase CWM?

Comment: Yes you flash a different recovery over the other one. You can flash either CWM or TWRP. But you should use which ever the guide is using.